# XCode 8 : Weird Storyboard issue that rolls back changes each time after it is saved

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode8

I am facing a really weird storyboard issue. I am using Version 8.0 (8A218a) . For one of my projects, I have two storyboard files, one for iPhone and one for iPad.

Both storyboards are behaving insanely: I open a storyboard file and make changes to a ViewController's view, then I save. I run the application and every thing is OK.

I switch to another file then open the stoyboard file again, and it loads back the old view! (changes subviews locations, to the left after I center them, the same subviews every time).

To track down the issue :

1- I made a copy of the project, cleaned, deleted derived data. Did not solve.

2- I thought about Source Control, so I disabled Git. Did not solve.

3- Unless it is a common bug, I am out of options.

The problem is that it does this in each of my 2 storyboard files. And when I open one and fix it them switch back to the second, I find it changed!

Did anyone face this weird issue with storyboard?
Any explanation and/or suggestion to solve it please?